# How can I extract the first 4 digits from an int? (Java)

Tags: java

I'm looking to find a way to convert a string to an int in order to then extract and return the first 4 digits in this int.

Note: It must remain as a String for the other methods to work properly, though.

Comment: `String.substring` should help...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following:

```
String str = "1234567890";
int fullInt = Integer.parseInt(str);
String first4char = str.substring(0,4);
int intForFirst4Char = Integer.parseInt(first4char);
```

Wherever you want integer for first four character use `intForFirst4Char` and where you wanna use string use appropriate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Harry

What's the purpose of the int fullInt? It would run the same without it wouldn't it? 

Thanks alot by the way!

Comment: @Jimmy: Nothing. May be you need it. Just shown use of `Integer.parseInt(string)`. Yes I know it will work without it.

Comment: Ok. Once again thanks. Just to clarify.. 

`codeString year = policy_no;
        Integer.parseInt(year);
        String first4char = year.substring(0,5);
        int intForFirst4Char = Integer.parseInt(first4char);
        return intForFirst4Char;`code

Will turn policy_no into an int and return the first 4 numbers?

Comment: @Jimmy: If my answer solves your problem then you should accept it. so others can know its a correct answer.

Comment: Ok sorry this is my first time on this site (as you probably guessed lol)

Comment: Won't this extract 5 characters (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) rather than 4?

Comment: @barrowc: +1, sorry my mistake. May be slip of finger. Thnx for showing my mistake. ;-)

Comment: Note that you will get an exception if `str` is shorter than 4 chars.

Answer (score 10):

```
Integer.parseInt(myIntegerString.substring(0, 4))
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: That could go out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

**You can either use the following:**

```
Integer.parseInt("123".substring(0, 2))
```

OR

```
int temp = 12345678;
int result = temp / (int)Math.pow(10, (int)(Math.log10(temp) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

public class ExtractingDigits {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int num = 1542,ans=0;

    for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
        ans=num%10;
        System.out.println(ans);
        num = num/10;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you are doing a little.  Also, is "main" the best name for a class method here?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you digits in an array

```
public Integer[] convertNumbertoArrayLtoR(Integer[] array, Integer number, Integer maxDivisor, Integer i)
{
    if (maxDivisor > 0)
    {
        Integer digit = number/maxDivisor;
        array[i] = digit;
        number = number%maxDivisor;
        maxDivisor = (int) Math.floor(maxDivisor/10);
        i++;
        convertNumbertoArrayLtoR(array, number, maxDivisor, i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Calling method

```
digitArrayLR = convertNumbertoArrayLtoR(digitArrayLR, numberInput, maxDivisor, 0);
```